# Group by contains nonaggregated column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to compute the average for each row in a table that has the same postcode and group it by that postcode and the year. I'm trying to run the following query

```
INSERT INTO processed_clean_properties (postcode,avgYearPostcodeNorm,latitude,longitude,yearSold)
SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)), latitude, longitude, yearSold 
FROM clean_properties 
GROUP BY postcode, yearSold
```

and getting the following error

**" Expression #3 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'forge.clean_properties.latitude' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by"**

I've looked into it and tried to disable the only_full_group_by from the sql_mode but it doesn't seem t o save any if the server is restarted it resets to default.

I've also tried adding all the selected columns to the group by condition as such

```
INSERT INTO processed_clean_properties (postcode,avgYearPostcodeNorm,latitude,longitude,yearSold)
SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)), latitude, longitude, yearSold 
FROM clean_properties 
GROUP BY postcode, norm, latitude, longitude, yearSold
```

Doing this makes the query run indefinitely without actually doing anything.

How can i correct the initial query to work with the full_group_by condition ?

Comment: The error message is telling, that you are doing something strange. I tend to agree.

Comment: I have a table that holds per row a postcode, latitude, longitude, price, normalisedPrice and year. I'm trying to insert into a new table the data in a  way that each postcode is grouped by the average normalisedPrice for that year.

Comment: The question is, if `latitude` and `longitude` are functionally dependent on `postcode`. If not, your query doesn't make sense. If yes, `latitude` and `longitude` shouldn't be in that table at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If including `latitude` and `longitude` in the `group by` cause the query to run forever, then this will probably have the same effect:

```
INSERT INTO processed_clean_properties (postcode, avgYearPostcodeNorm, latitude, longitude, yearSold)
    SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)),
           avg(latitude), avg(longitude), yearSold 
    FROM clean_properties 
    GROUP BY postcode, yearSold;
```

This gets the average of `latitude` and `longitude` for the rows for the postcode.  This isn't exact, but it is probably no worse than just grabbing arbitrary values.

Comment: The query executed but hasn't produced the expected result. I'm trying to group the rows in a way that for each year there will be unique postcodes with the norm averaged.

Comment: @Barrera . . . First, this should be doing exactly what you say -- one row per postcode each year.  Why do you care about latitude and longitude then?

Comment: Took a while to execute with the average lat and long but this seems to have produced exactly what I wanted it to. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6):

From the documentation:

> To tell MySQL to accept the query, you can use the `ANY_VALUE()` function.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Add [`ANY_VALUE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value) to the non-aggregated columns.  For example, `ANY_VALUE(latitude) AS latitude`.

You're bumping the fact that in MySQL 5.7 an old optimization -- allowing the server to nondeterministically return any one of the values from one row in each group for non-aggregated columns -- no longer works by default.  The old group by optimization is technically not valid SQL -- even though when used correctly, it's a huge performance winner. Using  `ANY_VALUE()` enables the old behavior while making it explicit and obvious that you are asking the server to trust you that you know what you're doing, that these columns are indeed functionally dependent on the group by, so returning any value from the group is fine since the should all be the same.

If they are not all the same within each group, of course, then your query is logically flawed.

Comment: Excellent answer! Explained just what I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need to do is remove the aggregated column `norm` from your GROUP BY:

```
INSERT INTO processed_clean_properties (postcode,avgYearPostcodeNorm,latitude,longitude,yearSold)
SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)), latitude, longitude, yearSold 
FROM clean_properties 
GROUP BY postcode, latitude, longitude, yearSold
```

If this still runs forever, it just means that grouping by all those additional columns is something that takes much longer. To resolve this you will need to tell us more on the table structure and more importantly, post the explain plan.

Another option, to set `only_full_group_by` off for good, you will need to set it in the my.cnf file. This file holds configurations that are used during server start up.

Comment: Alright, ill remove it and run the query again and report back. Thanks

Comment: The query executed but hasn't produced the expected result. I'm trying to group the rows in a way that for each year there will be only 1 postcode with the norm averaged.

Comment: @Barrera In that case, what should the latitude and longitude be? An average? Grouping by Lat and Long will obviously give many records per postcode. You can see the second part of my answer, or use average of latitude and longitude in Gordon's answer.

Comment: Each postcode represents a unique lat and long. I'm not sure what averaging the lat and long will achieve ?

Comment: @Barrera - if each postcode always had the same lat and long, you would get the result you wanted. It's apparently not the case. I believe same postcodes can have multiple lat and long, although they are all 'near'. That's why and average, a max or a min would not affect the lat and long too much so they are probably safe to use.

Comment: I'm currently rerunning the query with lat and long averaged. Although I've checked the data and each postcode is represented by the same lat long

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd attempt is almost correct, just remove the `norm` field from the group by list, since you do use an aggregate function on it.

```
INSERT INTO processed_clean_properties (postcode,avgYearPostcodeNorm,latitude,longitude,yearSold)
SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)), latitude, longitude, yearSold FROM clean_properties GROUP BY postcode, latitude, longitude, yearSold
```

If the above query is still slow, then you have to consider adding a multi-column index on the fields in the group by.

Comment: Alright, ill remove it and run the query again and report back. Thanks

Comment: The query executed but hasn't produced the expected result. I'm trying to group the rows in a way that for each year there will be only 1 postcode with the norm averaged.

Comment: Then that's the question you should have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You can as well consider getting the grouping first and then perform a join

```
SELECT cp.latitude, cp.longitude, x.postcode, x.avg_norm, x.yearSold
FROM clean_properties cp JOIN (
SELECT postcode, round(avg(norm)) as avg_norm, yearSold 
FROM clean_properties 
GROUP BY postcode, yearSold ) x ON cp.postcode = x.postcode;
```